# Returning more than 1000 rows in classic asp adodb.recordset

Tags: asp-classic, ado, recordset

My code in asp classic, doing a mssql database query:

```
        rs.pagesize = 1000  ' this should enable paging
        rs.maxrecords = 0   ' 0 = unlimited maxrecords      

        response.write "hello world 1<br>"
        rs.open strSql, conn 

        response.write "hello world 2<br>"
```

My output when there are fewer than 1000 rows returned is good.  More than 1000 rows and I don't get the "hello world 2".

I thought that setting pagesize sets up paging and thus allows all rows to be returned regardless of how many rows there are.  Without setting pagesize, paging is not enable and the limit is 1000 rows.  However my page is acting as if pagesize is not working at all.

Please advise.

Comment: Paging through Database Results N Records at a Time: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/121298-1.shtml

Comment: If you don't get to the "hello world 2" line it means you get error, it got nothing to do with paging. Remove any `on error resume next` lines from your code, run again and you'll most likely see the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your rs.open line to:

```
rs.Open strSQL, Conn, 3, 1, &H0001
```

Here's the breakdown of the function call and parameters:
recordsetobject.Open  Source, ActiveConnection, CursorType, LockType, Options

3 - adOpenStatic

1 - adLockReadOnly

&H0001 - adCmdText

I pull this from some old code of mine.  I don't remember why this combination of parameters is necessary but it's what is necessary to implement paging.

Unlimited records sounds great but I would set a limit even if it's quite hi.

If you are not getting the "Hello World 2" output, is there an error?  That would be helpful as well.

Comment: I'm trying your solution now.  I'd attempted to error trap the rs.open to see if there was an error reported.  The script just wound up hanging at that point.

Comment: You should at least get a script timeout back.  Do you have send errors to client turned on in IIS?  I assume you are not testing something like this on a production server.  Also, if you're using IE, you want to turn "Show friendly error messages" off.

Comment: My errors are sent to the windows logs.  I didn't get anything back at all.  I don't use IE.

Answer (score 1):

is it possible you are declaring your oRS.pagesize before you are opening the recordset?

Here is a good example of paging using getrows...

```
<!--VB ADO Constants file.  Needed for the ad... constants we use-->
<!-- #include file="adovbs.inc" -->
<%
' BEGIN USER CONSTANTS
Dim CONN_STRING
Dim CONN_USER
Dim CONN_PASS

' I'm using a DSN-less connection.
' To use a DSN, the format is shown on the next line:
'CONN_STRING = "DSN=DSNName;"

CONN_STRING = "DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("database.mdb") & ";"
CONN_STRING = CONN_STRING & "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};"

' This DB is unsecured, o/w you'd need to specify something here
CONN_USER = ""
CONN_PASS = ""

' Our SQL code - overriding values we just set
' Comment out to use Access
CONN_STRING = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=10.2.2.133;" _
    & "Initial Catalog=samples;Connect Timeout=15;" _
    & "Network Library=dbmssocn;"
CONN_USER = "samples"
CONN_PASS = "password"
' END USER CONSTANTS


' BEGIN RUNTIME CODE
' Declare our vars
Dim iPageSize       'How big our pages are
Dim iPageCount      'The number of pages we get back
Dim iPageCurrent    'The page we want to show
Dim strOrderBy      'A fake parameter used to illustrate passing them
Dim strSQL          'SQL command to execute
Dim objPagingConn   'The ADODB connection object
Dim objPagingRS     'The ADODB recordset object
Dim iRecordsShown   'Loop controller for displaying just iPageSize records
Dim I               'Standard looping var

' Get parameters
iPageSize = 10 ' You could easily allow users to change this

' Retrieve page to show or default to 1
If Request.QueryString("page") = "" Then
    iPageCurrent = 1
Else
    iPageCurrent = CInt(Request.QueryString("page"))
End If

' If you're doing this script with a search or something
' you'll need to pass the sql from page to page.  I'm just
' paging through the entire table so I just hard coded it.
' What you show is irrelevant to the point of the sample.
'strSQL = "SELECT * FROM sample ORDER BY id;"

' Sept 30, 1999: Code Change
' Based on the non stop questions about how to pass parameters
' from page to page, I'm implementing it so I can stop answering
' the question of how to do it.  I personally think this should
' be done based on the specific situation and is clearer if done
' in the same method on all pages, but it's really up to you.
' I'm going to be passing the ORDER BY parameter for illustration.

' This is where you read in parameters you'll need for your query.
' Read in order or default to id
'If Request.QueryString("order") = "" Then
'   strOrderBy = "id"
'Else
'   strOrderBy = Replace(Request.QueryString("order"), "'", "''")
'End If

' Make sure the input is one of our fields.
strOrderBy = LCase(Request.QueryString("order"))
Select Case strOrderBy
    Case "last_name", "first_name", "sales"
        ' A little pointless, but...
        strOrderBy = strOrderBy
    Case Else
        strOrderBy = "id"
End Select

' Build our SQL String using the parameters we just got.
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM sample ORDER BY " & strOrderBy & ";"

' Some lines I used while writing to debug... uh "test", yeah that's it!
' Left them FYI.
'strSQL = "SELECT * FROM sample WHERE id=1234 ORDER BY id;"
'strSQL = "SELECT * FROM sample;"
'Response.Write "SQL Query: " &  strSQL & "<BR>" & vbCrLf


' Now we finally get to the DB work...
' Create and open our connection
Set objPagingConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objPagingConn.Open CONN_STRING, CONN_USER, CONN_PASS

' Create recordset and set the page size
Set objPagingRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objPagingRS.PageSize = iPageSize

' You can change other settings as with any RS
'objPagingRS.CursorLocation = adUseClient
objPagingRS.CacheSize = iPageSize

' Open RS
objPagingRS.Open strSQL, objPagingConn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

' Get the count of the pages using the given page size
iPageCount = objPagingRS.PageCount

' If the request page falls outside the acceptable range,
' give them the closest match (1 or max)
If iPageCurrent > iPageCount Then iPageCurrent = iPageCount
If iPageCurrent < 1 Then iPageCurrent = 1

' Check page count to prevent bombing when zero results are returned!
If iPageCount = 0 Then
    Response.Write "No records found!"
Else
    ' Move to the selected page
    objPagingRS.AbsolutePage = iPageCurrent

    ' Start output with a page x of n line
    %>
    <p>
    <font size="+1">Page <strong><%= iPageCurrent %></strong>
    of <strong><%= iPageCount %></strong></font>
    </p>
    <%
    ' Spacing
    Response.Write vbCrLf

    ' Continue with a title row in our table
    Response.Write "<table border=""1"">" & vbCrLf

    ' Show field names in the top row
    Response.Write vbTab & "<tr>" & vbCrLf
    For I = 0 To objPagingRS.Fields.Count - 1
        Response.Write vbTab & vbTab & "<th>"
        Response.Write objPagingRS.Fields(I).Name
        Response.Write "</th>" & vbCrLf
    Next 'I
    Response.Write vbTab & "</tr>" & vbCrLf

    ' Loop through our records and ouput 1 row per record
    iRecordsShown = 0
    Do While iRecordsShown < iPageSize And Not objPagingRS.EOF
        Response.Write vbTab & "<tr>" & vbCrLf
        For I = 0 To objPagingRS.Fields.Count - 1
            Response.Write vbTab & vbTab & "<td>"
            Response.Write objPagingRS.Fields(I)
            Response.Write "</td>" & vbCrLf
        Next 'I
        Response.Write vbTab & "</tr>" & vbCrLf

        ' Increment the number of records we've shown
        iRecordsShown = iRecordsShown + 1
        ' Can't forget to move to the next record!
        objPagingRS.MoveNext
    Loop

    ' All done - close table
    Response.Write "</table>" & vbCrLf
End If

' Close DB objects and free variables
objPagingRS.Close
Set objPagingRS = Nothing
objPagingConn.Close
Set objPagingConn = Nothing


' Show "previous" and "next" page links which pass the page to view
' and any parameters needed to rebuild the query.  You could just as
' easily use a form but you'll need to change the lines that read
' the info back in at the top of the script.
If iPageCurrent > 1 Then
    %>
    <a href="db_paging.asp?page=<%= iPageCurrent - 1 %>&order=<%= Server.URLEncode(strOrderBy) %>">[&lt;&lt; Prev]</a>
    <%
End If

' You can also show page numbers:
For I = 1 To iPageCount
    If I = iPageCurrent Then
        %>
        <%= I %>
        <%
    Else
        %>
        <a href="db_paging.asp?page=<%= I %>&order=<%= Server.URLEncode(strOrderBy) %>"><%= I %></a>
        <%
    End If
Next 'I

If iPageCurrent < iPageCount Then
    %>
    <a href="db_paging.asp?page=<%= iPageCurrent + 1 %>&order=<%= Server.URLEncode(strOrderBy) %>">[Next &gt;&gt;]</a>
    <%
End If

' END RUNTIME CODE
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

paging is for just that, paging.

your code here is not enough to accomplish that but regardless of the code,  why are you trying to return a 1000 rows of data ????

nobody's going to read a 1000 rows of data and it will likely be very slow performance.

Comment: I have a customer that wants a report of orders and customers.  They will read 10000 lines of data if need be and they have a program to parse and analyze the data.  Yes, it's slow, but there is no interface in our application to create this.

Comment: I really don't think it is up to the community to determine how to code is to be used for, other than the developer himself. One may not think it is useful if he's not in the same situation as the original developer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code, I returned 4000+ rows from a sql server table in classic ASP.  It's not using the same method, but it doesn't suffer the limitations either.

```
strconnect = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=****;DATABASE=****;UID=****;PWD=****"
set conn=server.createobject("adodb.connection")
conn.open strconnect
set rs = conn.execute("select firstname from users")
if not rs.eof then
  f_Array = rs.getrows
end if
rs.close
set rs = nothing
conn.close
set conn = nothing

for x = 0 to ubound(f_Array, 2)
  response.write (x+1) & ". " & f_Array(0,x) & "<br />"
next
```

Comment: The only reason I am turning paging on is to get beyond the 1000 row limit per this article: [link](http://www.rlmueller.net/ADOAlternatives.htm) and many others.

Comment: I think I posted this answer to the wrong question. Very sorry. Since I'm here, I'm editing my answer with code that I just ran and returned 4000+ rows from a sql server using classic asp.  I have no idea if you'll find it helpful, but there it is. :)